# NodeJS image upload successful but Resize is not Working with GraphicsMagick

Tags: node.js, express, fs, graphicsmagick, formidable

I am trying to resize the image that has been uploaded. I have tested almost method i could find in the internet but none of them seems to work. I was able to upload the image to the to the server's folder but it is still keeping the full image size. What am I missing?

```
var formidable = require('formidable'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    gm = require('gm');

//handles image upload
exports.image = function (req, res) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        var file = files.file;
        var tempPath = file.path;

        var rename = makeid();
        var targetPath = path.resolve('./public/assets/images/upload/'+ file.name );

        fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err
            }
            gm( targetPath).resize(null, 50).on('finish', (function done(file) {
                console.log('done: ' + file);
            }).bind(null, file));

            return res.json({path: 'assets/images/upload/'+ file.name })
        })
    });
};

function makeid()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 15; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}
```

Comment: The resize is not done inplace, you have to use `write()` to write the resized file on the filesystem.

Comment: @ShanShan do you mean something like this? gm( targetPath).resize(null, 50)
            .write(path.resolve('./public/assets/images/upload/new.jpg'), function (err) {
                if (!err) console.log('done');
            });

Comment: @ShanShan , I am wondering will the targetpath image be available during the resizing too?

Comment: Yes, the source image is only read, it's not modified (unless you `write()` to the same path). I don't understand your second question, the source file is not locked so it's available to read.

Comment: I did as you said an i am having error of invalid parameter - resize @ShanShan